# How to use applyMatrix4 in react-three-fiber

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-three-fiber

I have this code in `THREE.js`:

```
  var RASToLPS = new THREE.Matrix4();
  RASToLPS.set(-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
  mesh.applyMatrix(RASToLPS);
  scene.add(mesh);
```

And I want to convert it to `react-three-fiber`. I have tried following code but it doesnt work:

```
    <mesh 
        {...props}
        geometry = {bufferGeometry}
        material = {material}
        applyMatrix4 = {matrix4 => {
            matrix4.set(-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)
        }}
        >
    </mesh>
```

Comment: applyMatrix4 is a function not a property, you just overwrite that function with another - but that isn't what you want. put a ref onto the mesh, useLayoutEffect will call you back before the object is rendered on screen, call applyMatrix4 on the ref. alternatively you can do `<mesh onUpdate={self => self.applyMatrix4(...)} .../>`

Answer (score 2):

I managed to make it work without the `applyMatrix4` mesh property using following code:

```
    const Component = ({
        bufferGeometry,
        material,
    }) => {
        const mesh = useRef<THREE.Mesh>()
    
        useEffect(() => { 
            if (mesh.current) {
                const RASToLPS = new THREE.Matrix4()
                RASToLPS.set(-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)
                mesh.current.applyMatrix4(RASToLPS)
            }
        }, [mesh])
    
        return (
            <mesh
                geometry = {bufferGeometry}
                material = {material}
                ref={mesh}
            >
            </mesh>
        )
    }
```

If anyone knows how to use `applyMatrix4` please answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not the whole answer ( I am having a similar issue) but try the following on your original-code `mesh` attrs:

- Replacing `applyMatrix4` with `matrix` (applyMatrix4 maybe defunct?)

Comment: Replacing `applyMatrix4` with `matrix` in my question code didnt work :(

Answer (score 0):

You can decompose the matrix into position, rotation and scale and apply those ... not ideal as what this does is essentially recompose the matrix after the fact, but until `matrix={matrix}` is supported, this works:

```
import { Euler, Matrix4, Quaternion, Vector3 } from 'three'

interface Decomposition {
  position: [number, number, number]
  rotation: [number, number, number]
  scale:    [number, number, number]
}

export function decompose(matrix: Matrix4): Decomposition {
  const position = new Vector3()
  const quaternion = new Quaternion()
  const rotation = new Euler()
  const scale = new Vector3()

  matrix.decompose(position, quaternion, scale)
  rotation.setFromQuaternion(quaternion)

  return {
    position: position.toArray() as [number, number, number],
    rotation: rotation.toArray() as [number, number, number],
    scale: scale.toArray() as [number, number, number],
  }
}
```

and then used:

```
interface Props {
  matrix: Matrix4
}

export function Example(props: Props): ReactElement {
  const { matrix } = props

  const decomposition = useMemo(() => decompose(matrix), [matrix])

  return (
    <mesh {...decomposition}>
      ...
    </mesh>
  )
}
```